# How to return a value into webpage

Tags: php, html, return

I have a simple webpage that displays the credit balance for calling cards.  So far without any problems, with HTML, PHP and mysql, I was able to retrieve the balance from a data base.  But I have to display the result in ANOTHER PAGE, wich looks akward because the page must reload.

Can I just load this value into a pre-drawed field under the input fields that collect the data from the customer?  Such as :

Account Number: 134556
PIN:  *****
|send|

Balance is: $12.36

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are users on SO. Could you offer any detail?

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I agree to annakata's point I'd recomend you [this](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichTutorial=ajax-basics). An ajax basics tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax as pointed out by KB22.

Ajax is a technique using which you can fetch content from your server using javascript and handle the request/response etc. without having to reload your page. It can happen in the background and a little code can be used to take the content fetched remotely and display it in the location(on the existing page) that you want.

Here is a simple Ajax Tutorial http://www.codecoffee.com/articles/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

I also think that AJAX will the best option. I would suggest you to use jQuery javascript library. It provides a nice wrapper for many functions. I usually use jQuery/AJAX/POST at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype +jQuery is cross-browser compliant & popular.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="your_action" method="POST" id="balance_checker_form">
    <input type="text" name="account_id" id="account_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Check Balance" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#balance_checker_form').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : $(this).attr('href'),
                success : function(html){
                    // Inject the response into the balance_response div.  Might want to do some highlighting or something to let the
                    // user know that the field was updated
                    $('#balance_response').html(html);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="balance_response"></div>
```

Try that.  Should help you get started in the correct direction.  You will need to include the jQuery library.  http://jquery.com/